# Required script for multiapl html table send on mail body

Tags: javascript

Request you please share with me Google app script for multipal HTML table sent on mail body with same format with background colour.

I Have no script for this, please help me in this case so i can submit my details to in my company

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.